# Can I know my opponent's Rafaam token?

Tags: hearthstone

There was an online debate during a hearthstone stream when a non-obvious token choice with Arch Thief Rafaam was supposed to surprise the opponent but the latter outbrained that attempt.

After calling him a streamhacker, some other viewers explained that the tokens of Arch Thief Rafaam are always discovered in the same order so one can always know which token was picked by one's opponent.

Has this ever been the case? If yes, is it still true?

Comment: http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Arch-Thief_Rafaam On notes it  says: While the order of the three choices is in a fixed order, it will be randomized for your opponent, therefore they cannot see what artifact you picked. And then linking to a reddit post. But nothing official from blizzard.

Comment: @Lyrion I guess you are being called by the crowd to post your own referenced answer

Comment: I know but the trouble is according to this post: https://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/3woizx/if_archthief_rafaam_generates_the_artifact_cards/ . People are indeed being able to see which one is picked. But ofcourse it might still be randomized, but there is still a 1/3 chance of a lucky guess. If I ever get time to test to make sure I will make an awnser.

Comment: It's generally pretty easy based on the board state to at least narrow the pick down to one of two, if not just outright choose.

Comment: @Waterseas which is why the streamer I watched tried to brain the opponent and that opponent's response made absolutely no sense.

Comment: @PierreArlaud Got any more specifics as to the reasoning for his choice? Also, a streamer really has no right to complain if someone stream snipes him

Comment: @Waterseas This goes for extended chat, in any case it was the viewers who accused the opponent of stream "hack" and some of the viewers tried to explain the guy could actually know which card was picked, hence the question. The streamer didn't complain himself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**. If it ever was the case, it's not now.

I dueled myself on an alt account in 5.2.0.13714 to test. Here are the results from the opponent's perspective after playing Arch-Thief Rafaam 11 times in 1 match:

**L** = Lantern of Power

**M** = Mirror of Doom

**T** = Timepiece of Horror

1. **L M T**
2. **T M L**
3. **T L M**
4. **M T L**
5. **T M L**
6. **L M T**
7. **M L T**
8. **T M L**
9. **L T M**
10. **L T M**
11. **L M T**